# App Crashing if the internet goes off in mid in android

Tags: android, json, crash

I am fetching a json schema in my android app and it is working fine. But the problem is if the internet goes off in mid while fetching the data, the app crashes. How can I handle this exception?

I am calling `new LoadPlaces().execute();`and then in the doInBackground method this is called `googlePlaces.search(lat1, lon1, radius, types);`which fetches the json data and assign it to an object.

This is the search method

```
public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String types)
        throws Exception {

    this._latitude = latitude;
    this._longitude = longitude;
    this._radius = radius;

    try {

        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
        request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
        request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
        request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius);                            // in meters
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
        if(types != null)
            request.getUrl().put("types", types);

        PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
        // Check log cat for places response status
        Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
        return list;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please do reply to this and help me, it is of utmost importance for me. I am ready to offer bounty but please help me out. Thanks

**Logcat**

```
06-08 05:15:25.335  32008-32008/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.atifarain.customizedcamera, PID: 32008
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.atifarain.customizedcamera.MainActivity$LoadPlaces$1.run(MainActivity.java:485)
        at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4757)
        at com.example.atifarain.customizedcamera.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:479)
        at com.example.atifarain.customizedcamera.MainActivity$LoadPlaces.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:446)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**MainActivity**

```
class LoadPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // creating Places class object
        googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

        try {
            // Separeate your place types by PIPE symbol "|"
            // If you want all types places make it as null
            //String types = "establishment|art_gallery|museum|place_of_worship";
            //String types = "art_gallery|museum";
            String types = "art_gallery|museum|place_of_worship";
            double radius = 1000;       // 1000 meters
            // get nearest places
            nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(lat1, lon1, radius, types);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI from background
     * thread, otherwise you will get error
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW
                 * */
                // Get json response status
                String status = nearPlaces.status;

                // Check for all possible status
                if(status.equals("OK")){
                    // Successfully got places details
                    if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
                        // loop through each place
                        ArrayList<String> coordinates = new ArrayList<String>();
                        ArrayList<Double> bearings = new ArrayList<Double>();

                        for (NearbyPlaceNodes p : nearPlaces.results) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // NearbyPlaceNodes reference is used to get "place full details"
                            map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);
                            map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);          // NearbyPlaceNodes name

                            double lat2 = p.geometry.location.lat;
                            double lon2 = p.geometry.location.lng;

                            double _bearing = bearing(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
                            bearings.add(_bearing);

                            String lat = Double.toString(lat2);
                            String lon = Double.toString(lon2);
                            String latlon = lat+","+lon;

                            coordinates.add(latlon);
                            String bearing_ = String.format("%.04f",_bearing);

                            String nearbyDat = latlon+","+bearing_+","+p.name;
                            nearbyData.add(nearbyDat);

                            placesListItems.add(map);       // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                        }

                        MainActivity.this.onBackgroundTaskDataObtained(nearbyData);
                    }
                }
```

Line# 485 =>    `String status = nearPlaces.status;`

Line# 479 =>             `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {`

Line# 446 =>  `class LoadPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a network malfunction on the middle of your `search` method will trigger an exception that will be caught here:

```
catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

You return null, which will be assigned to `nearPlaces` on your `doInBackground` method:

```
nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(lat1, lon1, radius, types);
```

So on the `onPostExecute` method, the variable `nearPlaces`is null and you are trying to access a field on a null variable:

```
String status = nearPlaces.status;
```

Causing the crash you see on the logs. The simple and quick solution is to check if `nearPlaces` is null before doing any action on your `onPostExecute`, and maybe present an error message instead.

By the way, doing this on `onPostExecute` is redundant:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 public void run() { ... }
})
```

`onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` are always by default called on the UI thread, that's the main reason for the existence of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).